# Running tomcat on Mac

Tags: apache, terminal, tomcat7

Hi im trying to run tomcat over the terminal in mac, so i type ./startup.sh to execute the script.The terminal then gives me the following:

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/kimmy/Documents/Apache/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/kimmy/Documents/Apache/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/kimmy/Documents/Apache/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/kimmy/Documents/Apache/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/kimmy/Documents/Apache/tomcats/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

When i try to visit the local host to check if the tomcat server is running the browser says can not connect to server.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: By default Tomcat listens on port 8080. Are you connecting to `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: yes i am connecting to http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

tomcat server by default runs on port no 9999 on mac.

To know the port no on which tomcat is running, check the terminal after server is on. check the line "server started on......"

using this port no you can request by following

http://localhost:9999

this will open server page.

Hope this helps.